# Android : Calculate sum and group by month (SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Is there are any option to select amount, group them by month and calculate sum. I tried to get total sum of each month and pass it to ArrayList.
Example of data:

```
Amount    Date
230       04/03/19
500       05/03/19
400       04/04/19
600       06/04/19
100       04/03/19
...       ...
```

My code structure

```
private String CREATE_BILLS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BILLS + "("
            + COLUMN_BILL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_DATE_STRING + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_COMPANY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_USER+"("+COLUMN_USER_ID+"));";

 public ArrayList<Bills> getDateByUserID(int userID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // sorting orders
        ArrayList<Bills> listBillsDates = new ArrayList<Bills>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BILLS, new String[] { COLUMN_BILL_ID,
                        COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID, COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, COLUMN_AMOUNT, COLUMN_DATE_STRING, COLUMN_COMPANY_NAME, COLUMN_CATEGORY}, COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(userID) }, COLUMN_DATE_STRING, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bills bills = new Bills();
                bills.setAmount(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_AMOUNT)));
                bills.setDateString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE_STRING)));
                // Adding record to list
                listBillsDates.add(bills);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // return category list
        return listBillsDates;
    }
```

Comment: Step 1 is to store your dates in one of the formats supported by sqlite's date and time functions. See that list [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Once you've done that, you can `GROUP BY` on an expression using `strftime()` to get just the month from a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that a query based upon :-

```
SELECT sum(COLUMN_AMOUNT) AS Monthly_Total,substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,4) AS Month_and_Year
    FROM TABLE_BILLS 
    WHERE COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID = 1
  GROUP BY substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,4)
    ORDER BY substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,7,2)||substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,4,2)
;
```

- Note that other columns values would be arbritary results and as such cannot really be relied upon (fine if the data is always the same). Hence they have not been included.

Will produce the results that you want :-

e.g.

Using the following, to test the SQL :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_BILLS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_BILLS (
    COLUMN_BILL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID INTEGER,
    COLUMN_DESCRIPTION TEXT,
    COLUMN_AMOUNT INTEGER,
    COLUMN_DATE_STRING TEXT,
    COLUMN_COMPANY_NAME TEXT,
    COLUMN_CATEGORY TEXT)
    ;

-- Add the Testing data
INSERT INTO TABLE_BILLS (
    COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID, COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, COLUMN_AMOUNT, COLUMN_DATE_STRING, COLUMN_COMPANY_NAME,COLUMN_CATEGORY)
VALUES 
        (1,'blah',230,'04/03/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(1,'blah',500,'05/03/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(1,'blah',400,'04/04/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(1,'blah',600,'06/04/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(1,'blah',100,'04/03/19','cmpny','category')

        -- Extra data for another id to check exclusion
        ,(2,'blah',230,'04/03/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(2,'blah',500,'05/03/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(2,'blah',400,'04/04/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(2,'blah',600,'06/04/19','cmpny','category')
        ,(2,'blah',100,'04/03/19','cmpny','category')
;

SELECT sum(COLUMN_AMOUNT) AS Monthly_Total,substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,4) AS Month_and_Year
    FROM TABLE_BILLS 
    WHERE COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID = 1
  GROUP BY substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,4)
    ORDER BY substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,7,2)||substr(COLUMN_DATE_STRING,4,2)
;
```

**Results id :-**

[image]

The above can then be converted for use by the SQLiteDatabase **query** method. So your method could be something like :-

```
public ArrayList<Bills> getDateByUserID(int userID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String tmpcol_monthly_total = "Monthly_Total";
    String tmpcol_month_year = "Month_and_Year";
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            "sum(" + COLUMN_AMOUNT + ") AS " + tmpcol_monthly_total,
            "substr(" + COLUMN_DATE_STRING + ",4) AS " + tmpcol_month_year
    };
    String whereclause = COLUMN_BILL_USER_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(userID)};
    String groupbyclause = "substr(" + COLUMN_DATE_STRING + ",4)";
    String orderbyclause = "substr(" + COLUMN_DATE_STRING + ",7,2)||substr(" + COLUMN_DATE_STRING + ",4,2)";
    ArrayList<Bills> listBillsDates = new ArrayList<Bills>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BILLS, columns, whereclause,
            whereargs, groupbyclause, null, orderbyclause, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Bills bills = new Bills();
            bills.setAmount(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(tmpcol_monthly_total)));
            bills.setDateString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tmpcol_month_year))); //<<<<<<<<<< NOTE data is MM/YY (otherwise which date to use? considering result will be arbrirtaryy)
            // Adding record to list
            listBillsDates.add(bills);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return category list
    return listBillsDates;
}
```

- The above has been tested and run and using the following code :-

  ```
  ArrayList<Bills> myMonthlyTotals = mDBHelper.getDateByUserID(1);
  Log.d("BILLSCOUNT","The number of bills extracted was " + String.valueOf(myMonthlyTotals.size()));
  for (Bills b: myMonthlyTotals) {
      Log.d("MONTHYLTOTAL","Monthly total for " + b.getDateString() + " was " + String.valueOf(b.getAmount()));

  }
  ```
- In an activity, resulted in the following in the log

:-

```
04-14 11:58:25.876 16653-16653/? D/BILLSCOUNT: The number of bills extracted was 2
04-14 11:58:25.877 16653-16653/? D/MONTHYLTOTAL: Monthly total for 03/19 was 830
04-14 11:58:25.877 16653-16653/? D/MONTHYLTOTAL: Monthly total for 04/19 was 1000
```

- Please consider the comments in regard to values from non-aggreagted columns be arbitrary values. As per :-
- > *Each non-aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting entirely of NULL values.* [SELECT - 3. Generation of the set of result rows.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

As per the comments, using recognised [date formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) can make the underlying SQL simpler and likely more efficient.